# how to get any bone orientation from kinect v2 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, kinect

i am using SDK 2.0 with kinect for windows v2 and c#.
i am able to get the x,y,z coordinates for each joint but i want to get the orientation of the bones with respect to the parent bones.
any help will be appreciated.
thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Kinect for Windows V2, You can get the bone orientation data from [`JointOrientation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.jointorientation.aspx) class.